# how use one scope between two based on a condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I have a model `POSTS`. in that i have two scopes in this model `active`, `inactive`. i want use one of it `PostsController` based on `params[:active]` value. like following

```
if params[:active] == "true"
 @posts = POSTS.where some_condition
       .include some_thing
       .active
       .page
       .per
else
  @posts = POSTS.where some_condition
       .include
       .inactive
       .page
       .per
 end
```

is there any better way to do the same thing? i tried many ways to do it. but i couldn't. help me. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@posts = POSTS.where some_condition
              .include some_thing
              .public_send(params[:active] == "true" ? :active : :inactive)
              .page
              .per
```

[`Object#public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send).